# Richtextbox to take up half half the form width

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 Richtextboxws on the form. I need for each textbox to take up half the form width and full height. also, I need those textboxes to keep the above mentioned proportions even when then the form size is changed on the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TableLayoutPanel` with the default 2 columns, remove the last row so you only have 1 row.  By default, the columns SizeType is set to a 50%, so both columns will grow and shrink proportionally.

Place a RichTextBox control in each panel of the TableLayoutPanel control.

Set the `DockStyle=Fill` for the TableLayoutPanel and the two RichTextBox controls.

Comment: +1 to the tableLayoutPanel solution, however, I have found that for controls INSIDE the TableLayoutPanel, you need to set the .Anchor property (to TOP+LEFT+RIGHT+BOTTOM) rather than the .Dock property.